# How to run Powershell script via batch file without secondary file

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, cmd

I have two files, one is called `Startmenu.bat` and the second one is `test.ps1`

#### Startmenu.bat:

```
@echo ON
PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& {Start-Process PowerShell -ArgumentList '-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "C:\test.ps1"' -Verb RunAs}";
```

#### test.ps1:

```
Get-AppXPackage -AllUsers | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}
```

These two files are working properly if I run `Startmenu.bat` and `test.ps1` is placed to C:\

But my question if can I make just one file? Can I somehow include the Powershell script inside first file, I mean `Startmenu.bat`? I want to make just a single file and I really don't know how.

My Start menu in Windows 10 is broken and I have to run Powershell command to access Start Menu (at every boot).

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in the question! You're running PowerShell first with the `-Command` parameter, which runs PowerShell commands directly; as it happens you're using this to open PowerShell again (with the RunAs verb so that it's elevated). You could simply use `-Command` again instead of using `-File`.

Another way is to use the `-EncodedCommand` parameter and Base64 encode your PowerShell commands.

See the very end of the help when you run `powershell.exe -help`:

```
# To use the -EncodedCommand parameter:
$command = 'dir "c:\program files" '
$bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($command)
$encodedCommand = [Convert]::ToBase64String($bytes)
powershell.exe -encodedCommand $encodedCommand
```

Comment: I tried
`@echo ON
PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& {Start-Process PowerShell -ArgumentList '-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "Get-AppXPackage -AllUsers | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}"' -Verb RunAs}";`

And I got error _"Foreach is not recognised as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."_

Comment: @cristi_ you need to be careful about embedding quote inside of other quotes, you end up having to do annoying escape sequences. This is where `-EncodedCommand` comes in; you don't have to worry about any of that! Give it a try.

Comment: I tried to implemented -EncodedCommand but I don't know how it's gonna still work in a batch file. And still didn't manage to figure out how it should work with -EncodedCommand. :/

Comment: I tried this `@echo ON
PowerShell -Command "& {Start-Process PowerShell -ArgumentList '-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -EncodedCommand R2V0LUFwcFhQYWNrYWdlIC1BbGxVc2VycyB8IEZvcmVhY2gge0FkZC1BcHB4UGFja2FnZSAtRGlzYWJsZURldmVsb3BtZW50TW9kZSAtUmVnaXN0ZXIgIiQoJF8uSW5zdGFsbExvY2F0aW9uKVxBcHBYTWFuaWZlc3QueG1sIn0= -Verb RunAs}";` but it's not working. And I don't know why :/

Comment: @cristi_ it looks to me like you used ASCII instead of Unicode. The Base64 encoded string must be Unicode; did you convert it using a web  page converter or something? Most of them don't support Unicode. The code example I showed will properly convert it.

Comment: My bad. So the code should be: `@echo ON PowerShell -Command "& {Start-Process PowerShell -ArgumentList '-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -EncodedCommand RwBlAHQALQBBAHAAcABYAFAAYQBjAGsAYQBnAGUAIAAtAEEAbABsAFUAcwBlAHIAcwAgAHwAIABGAG8AcgBlAGEAYwBoACAAewBBAGQAZAAtAEEAcABwAHgAUABhAGMAawBhAGcAZQAgAC0ARABpAHMAYQBiAGwAZQBEAGUAdgBlAGwAbwBwAG0AZQBuAHQATQBvAGQAZQAgAC0AUgBlAGcAaQBzAHQAZQByACAAIgAkACgAJABfAC4ASQBuAHMAdABhAGwAbABMAG8AYwBhAHQAaQBvAG4AKQBcAEEAcABwAFgATQBhAG4AaQBmAGUAcwB0AC4AeABtAGwAIgB9AA== -Verb RunAs}";` But still not working for me :(

Comment: I think batch file doesn't like Unicode characters and I see weird letters when I execute file. :/

Comment: I think -EncodedCommand is not a good ideea. I still think I can make something really easy like `@echo ON PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& {Start-Process PowerShell -ArgumentList '-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "Get-AppXPackage -AllUsers | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}"' -Verb RunAs}";`
But the problem with this approach is that I get "Foreach is not recognised as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.". The vertical bar is guilty I think. Other solutions? :(